# Remove Duplicate value using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT 2.0. My desired output should have unique epc element values without any duplicate.
I need to compare all the child elements as see if there are any duplicates

```
 <EPCISDocument xmlns:cbvmda="urn:epcglobal:cbv:mda"
               xmlns:ns5="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1" schemaVersion="1.2"
               creationDate="2020-02-21T19:14:36.974Z"
               xmlns="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1">
 <EPCISBody xmlns="">
  <EventList>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546566</epc>
     <epc>100002546567</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546566</epc>
     <epc>100002546567</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546568</epc>
     <epc>100002546569</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546568</epc>
     <epc>100002546570</epc>
     <epc>100002546571</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546571</epc>
     <epc>100002546572</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546573</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
    <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546573</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
  </EventList>
 </EPCISBody>
</EPCISDocument>
```

---

My Output(Incorrect)

```
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns6:EPCISDocument xmlns:ns6="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1">
   <EPCISBody>
      <EventList>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546566</epc>
               <epc>100002546567</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546566</epc>
               <epc>100002546567</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546568</epc>
               <epc>100002546569</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546568</epc>
               <epc>100002546569</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546568</epc>
               <epc>100002546570</epc>
               <epc>100002546571</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546568</epc>
               <epc>100002546570</epc>
               <epc>100002546571</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546571</epc>
               <epc>100002546572</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
         <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
               <epc>100002546573</epc>
               <action/>
            </epcList>
         </ObjectEvent>
      </EventList>
   </EPCISBody>
</ns6:EPCISDocument>
```

---

```
**Desired Output:**
```

---

```
<EPCISDocument xmlns:cbvmda="urn:epcglobal:cbv:mda"
               xmlns:ns5="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1" schemaVersion="1.2"
               creationDate="2020-02-21T19:14:36.974Z"
               xmlns="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1">
 <EPCISBody xmlns="">
  <EventList>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546566</epc>
     <epc>100002546567</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>   
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546568</epc>
     <epc>100002546569</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>    
     <epc>100002546570</epc>
     <epc>100002546571</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>    
     <epc>100002546572</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>
   <ObjectEvent>
    <action>ADD</action>
    <epcList>
     <epc>100002546573</epc>
    </epcList>
   </ObjectEvent>   
  </EventList>
 </EPCISBody>
</EPCISDocument>
```

---

```
**My XSLT**
```

---

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns6:EPCISDocument>
      <EPCISBody>
        <EventList>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns6:EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/ObjectEvent/epcList"
                              composite='yes' group-by="epc">
            <ObjectEvent>
              <epcList>
                <xsl:for-each select="epc">
                  <epc>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </epc>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <action>
                  <xsl:value-of select="action"/>
                </action>
              </epcList>
            </ObjectEvent>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </EventList>
      </EPCISBody>
    </ns6:EPCISDocument>
  </xsl:template>
```

I am using XSLT 2.0. 
My desired output should have unique epc element values without any duplicate.
I need to compare all the child elements as see if they are exact duplicates

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? Any chance you can use to Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 to be able to use XSLT 3 where it might be that `for-each-group composite="yes" group-by="epcList/epc"` solves that? It is not quite clear to me whether your condition means that an element is a duplicate if any `epc` has a duplicate or if all have a duplicate. The latter would indeed be solvable with XSLT 3 and `composite="yes"`.

Comment: Please don't say "I tried everything and it didn't work". Tell us what you tried, and how it failed. Then we can see where you've gone wrong, and explain your mistake so you don't make it again.

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could do this pretty easily with an xsl:key ([see fiddle here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRApo))...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="epc" match="epc" use="normalize-space()"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="
    ObjectEvent[not(epcList/epc[count(.|key('epc',normalize-space())[1])=1])]|
    epc[not(count(.|key('epc',normalize-space())[1])=1)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I'm not sure what's supposed to happen when an `action` other than "ADD" is encountered. (Right now, `action` is ignored.)